# What 's the largest number of consecutive integers such that each is divisible by a prime $\le p_n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

> What's the best upper bound for the largest number of consecutive integers such that each is divisible by a prime ≤$p_n$?

Is it less than ${p_n}^2$?

Comment: *Consecutive integers ?* $p\mid n \implies p \not\mid n+1$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I think they are allowed to be divisible by different primes, so long as each is $\leq p_n$.

Comment: @kccu yeah, they are.

Comment: But not divisible by any prime larger than $p_n$?  Between $p_n < p_{n+1} < 2p_n$..

Comment: A good candidate starts with the number $(p_{n+1}-1)!+2$

Comment: @fleablood according to http://oeis.org/A058989, there exists 89 consecutive numbers that are divisible by primes up to the 14th prime (43). The longest sequence doesn't necessarily start at $p_n$.

Comment: @KeithBackman i think we could go as low as $p_n \#$ as we can prove the existence of more than one totative of it.

Comment: But at least one of the consecutive number must be divisible by the $15$th prime ($47$).

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003309

Comment: @KeithBackman $1_{\gcd(a,p_n\#)=1}$ is $p_n\#$ periodic, ie. starting at $m$ is the same as starting at $m\bmod p_n\#$ in your example it means starting at $2$ (this argument gives the trivial upper bound $p_n\#-\phi(p_n\#)$). Brad, why did you guess $p_n^2$ ?